Why is my array of objects not being displayed from JavaScript to HTML properly?


const initial = [
  { name: "Alice", price: 30, occupation: "Writer" },
  { name: "Bob", price: 50, occupation: "Teacher"}
]
    
   


const extraFreelancers = [
    { name: "Dr. Slice", price: 25, occupation: "Gardener" },
    { name: "Dr. Pressure", price: 51, occupation: "Programmer" },
    { name: "Prof. Possibility", price: 43, occupation: "Teacher" },
    { name: "Prof. Prism", price: 81, occupation: "Teacher" },
    { name: "Dr. Impulse", price: 43, occupation: "Teacher" },
    { name: "Prof. Spark", price: 76, occupation: "Programmer" },
    { name: "Dr. Wire", price: 47, occupation: "Teacher" },
    { name: "Prof. Goose", price: 72, occupation: "Driver" },
  ]; 

const maxLancers = 5;

render();


const addFreelancerInterval = setInterval(addFreelancer, 5000);

function render() {
    const container = document.querySelector(".container")

    for(let i = 0; i < initial.length; i++){
    const usersBox = document.createElement("div")
    usersBox.className = "usersBox"
    
    const name = document.createElement("p")
    const price = document.createElement("p")
    const occ = document.createElement("p")
    
    name.innerText = `${initial[i].name}`
    price.innerText = `$${initial[i].price}`
    occ.innerText = `${initial[i].occupation}`
    
    usersBox.appendChild(name)
    usersBox.appendChild(price)
    usersBox.appendChild(occ)
    
    container.appendChild(usersBox)
  }
}


function addFreelancer() {
    const freelancer = extraFreelancers[Math.floor(Math.random() * extraFreelancers.length)];
    initial.push(freelancer);
    render();
    

    if (initial.length >= maxLancers) {
      clearInterval(addFreelancerInterval);
    }
    averageStartingPrice();
}

const avg = document.createElement("p")
avg.className = "avg"
avg.innerText = `${averageStartingPrice()}`;


function averageStartingPrice() {
  const totalStartingPrice = initial.reduce((acc, freelancer) => acc += freelancer.price, 0);
  return totalStartingPrice / initial.length;
}
html {
    background-color: white;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.usersBox{
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 1000px;
  }

#box {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin:100px;
    padding: 0px;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

#title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1000px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
    margin: 10px;

}

h2 {
    margin: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#lists{
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
}

h3 {
    margin: 110px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Freelancer Forum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="box">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Freelancer Forum</h1>
            <p class="avg">The average starting price is 
            </p>
            <h2>Available Freelancers: </h2> 
            <div id="lists">
                <h3>Name</h3>
                <h3>Price</h3>
                <h3>Occupation</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">  
        </div>
    </div>


        <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



I have created two functions to display an array of objects onto an HTML page.
function render() {
    const container = document.querySelector(".container")

    for(let i = 0; i < initial.length; i++){
    const usersBox = document.createElement("div")
    usersBox.className = "usersBox"
    
    const name = document.createElement("p")
    const price = document.createElement("p")
    const occ = document.createElement("p")
    
    name.innerText = `${initial[i].name}`
    price.innerText = `$${initial[i].price}`
    occ.innerText = `${initial[i].occupation}`
    
    usersBox.appendChild(name)
    usersBox.appendChild(price)
    usersBox.appendChild(occ)
    
    container.appendChild(usersBox)
  }
}

The above function to display the array onto HTML.
function addFreelancer() {
    const freelancer = extraFreelancers[Math.floor(Math.random() * extraFreelancers.length)];
    initial.push(freelancer);
    render();
    

    if (initial.length >= maxLancers) {
      clearInterval(addFreelancerInterval);
    }
    averageStartingPrice();
}

And this function to add objects from another array to the initial array.
For some reason, the output on the HTML page is iterating the same initial array over and over again instead of just adding the new objects to the list. Below is a screenshot of what the output looks like (note the repeated "Alice" and "Bob" objects, which are the initial array).
HTML DISPLAY
I really have no idea where the issue is. I am very new to JavaScript and HTML so I apologize if it is something simple that was overlooked. Any help is greatly appreciated!
(https://github.com/antjuh/Unit2.FreelancerForum.git) GitHub for anyone interested in further details.
EDIT: Apologies, I have added JavaScript, HTML, and CSS to the post for easy access.

So can you add your full html and js, so people can test it please?

we have no idea what extraFreelancers contains, or what initial is. Also, since you push to initial a random freelancer, of course you can get the same one more than once - random numbers are random

Sorry, I have added the full code to the post so you all can see what is going on.

oh, and every time you render, you render what's already in initial plus the added freelancer

Yes, every time it renders, it renders what is in initial, plus the added freelancer. I want the code to only display a total of five objects(people). I am confused why it keeps printing the first two objects of initial out instead of just adding a new object.

Note, that you have tabular content and as such you should use a table with a correct table head instead of headlines!

The problem is that you are repeating the same initial list, which has the same people. Thus it will repeat the same person again.
So what I did is add a variable that whenever the render runs it sets it to the length of the initial list, so when the something is added to the list it doesn't repeat the same people again.


const initial = [
  { name: "Alice", price: 30, occupation: "Writer" },
  { name: "Bob", price: 50, occupation: "Teacher"}
]
    
   


const extraFreelancers = [
    { name: "Dr. Slice", price: 25, occupation: "Gardener" },
    { name: "Dr. Pressure", price: 51, occupation: "Programmer" },
    { name: "Prof. Possibility", price: 43, occupation: "Teacher" },
    { name: "Prof. Prism", price: 81, occupation: "Teacher" },
    { name: "Dr. Impulse", price: 43, occupation: "Teacher" },
    { name: "Prof. Spark", price: 76, occupation: "Programmer" },
    { name: "Dr. Wire", price: 47, occupation: "Teacher" },
    { name: "Prof. Goose", price: 72, occupation: "Driver" },
  ]; 

const maxLancers = 5;

let initialListThingy = 0 // I don't know what to name this

render();


const addFreelancerInterval = setInterval(addFreelancer, 5000);



function render() {
    
    const container = document.querySelector(".container")
    

    for(i = initialListThingy; i < initial.length; i++){
    const usersBox = document.createElement("div")
    usersBox.className = "usersBox"
    
    const name = document.createElement("p")
    const price = document.createElement("p")
    const occ = document.createElement("p")
    
    name.innerText = `${initial[i].name}`
    price.innerText = `$${initial[i].price}`
    occ.innerText = `${initial[i].occupation}`
    
    usersBox.appendChild(name)
    usersBox.appendChild(price)
    usersBox.appendChild(occ)
    
    container.appendChild(usersBox)
  }
  initialListThingy = initial.length
}


function addFreelancer() {
    const freelancer = extraFreelancers[Math.floor(Math.random() * extraFreelancers.length)];
    initial.push(freelancer);
    render();
    

    if (initial.length >= maxLancers) {
      clearInterval(addFreelancerInterval);
    }
    averageStartingPrice();
}

const avg = document.createElement("p")
avg.className = "avg"
avg.innerText = `${averageStartingPrice()}`;


function averageStartingPrice() {
  const totalStartingPrice = initial.reduce((acc, freelancer) => acc += freelancer.price, 0);
  return totalStartingPrice / initial.length;
}
html {
    background-color: white;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.usersBox{
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 1000px;
  }

#box {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin:100px;
    padding: 0px;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

#title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1000px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
    margin: 10px;

}

h2 {
    margin: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#lists{
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
}

h3 {
    margin: 110px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Freelancer Forum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="box">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Freelancer Forum</h1>
            <p class="avg">The average starting price is 
            </p>
            <h2>Available Freelancers: </h2> 
            <div id="lists">
                <h3>Name</h3>
                <h3>Price</h3>
                <h3>Occupation</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">  
        </div>
    </div>


        <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




This works great thank you! On an aside, would you happen to know how I can put "averageStartingPrice();" into a ?

@antjuh that is a different question to which you should ask a different question at SO. However, I recommend you do some basic research effort first. There are tons of tutorials on the web and answers on SO.

AS i understand, your problem is why "Alice" and "Bob" are repeated in result?
Let's go through code:

initial index.html Page Load render(); function will exeute and display because initial array has 2 items "Alice" and "Bob"

After 5s interval addFreelancer function is called. it will randomly pick any element from extraFreelancers array And add this element to initial array initial.push(freelancer);

now initial array has 3 items. render(); will display these three items.


but you are not removing the already displayed items in step 1. now every time you will call render old elements and newly add element will display again and again.
